# BeautifulSoup Extracting values in a Div Tag in python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

**From the code given below I need to extract the value of 96 **

```
<div class="price">
<span id="product-promotion-price">Rs 96.00</span> 
<br>
```

**I tried the following code.But it didn't work**

```
product_name_glomark = 'https://glomark.lk/coconut/p/11624'
html2 = requests.get(product_name_glomark).content
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(html2,'html.parser')

price_glomark = soup2.find("div",{"class":"price"}, {"id":"product-promotion-price"}).get_text()
product_name_glomark = soup2.find("div",{"class":"product-title"}).get_text()
```

**Given below is the output**

[image: As you can see it returns nothing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract direct from script tag where listed. I return as float as future values may not be integers

```
import requests, re

product_name_glomark = 'https://glomark.lk/coconut/p/11624'
html2 = requests.get(product_name_glomark).text
price = float(re.search(r'"price": "(\d+?)"', html2).group(1))
print(price)
```

Comment: It gives the value but not the desired output format

Comment: what is the desired output format please? I read your line that said `I need to extract the value of 96`.

Comment: Laughs   COCONUT - Item#mr-2058 Rs.:  89.0
Glomark  Coconut Rs.:  96.0

This is the expected format.